Use the reasoner of the library owlready2 on an ontology already in a file
I have used owlready2 (https://owlready2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
I'm trying to

read an ontology on disk (onto.xml)
add a swrl rule
run the reasoner on it
and then save the resulting ontology with the new facts inferred.

I'm a bit stuck right now.
I tried the examples, but I cannot understand why I have to define classes in the python program (https://owlready2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rule.html) I tried this but I already have  Classes, ObjectProperties and the Individuals in my onto.xml.
Defining classes, objectproperties and individuals all in the python works, the reasoner answers.
My prefered examples are this kind https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69224096/swrl-rules-in-owl-2/78320189 with the brothers and uncles, quite easy to follow.
Bye
Here's a basic_reader.py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# Owlready2 currently reads the following file format: RDF/XML, OWL/XML, NTriples. The file format is automatically detected.
import argparse
import os

import owlready2 as owl

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--ontology", help="ontology file", required=True)
args = parser.parse_args()

path2in = args.ontology
onto = owl.get_ontology(path2in).load()

print(list(onto.classes()))

print(list(onto.individuals()))

That works with an ontology on a file
if you ontology is in ttl format you can convert it on the fly like this :
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# Owlready2 currently reads the following file format: RDF/XML, OWL/XML, NTriples. The file format is automatically detected.
import argparse
import os

import owlready2 as owl

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--ontology", help="ontology file as a ttl file", required=True)
args = parser.parse_args()

path2in = args.ontology
path2out = path2in.replace(".ttl", ".xml")

cmd2 = f"ontospy ser -f xml {path2in} 2>/dev/null > {path2out}"
os.system(cmd2)


onto = owl.get_ontology(path2out).load()

print(list(onto.classes()))

print(list(onto.individuals()))


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

As the bot is asking code : my goal would be to use the answer  from @cknoll but not defining the class nor the individuals in the python program, having everything in onto.owl but the rules. Even the rules could be in the owl file in fact (like this you can run it in protégé too, with the plugin swrl)
The python program would be only a reasonner.

I reply to myself with this working example :
def main():
    """add a swrl rule."""
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--ontology", help="ontology file", required=True)
    parser.add_argument(
        "--destination", help="destination ontology file", required=True
    )

    args = parser.parse_args()

    input_file = args.ontology
    output_file = args.destination

    onto = owl.get_ontology(input_file).load()

    with onto:
        swrl_rule = """ http://maccve/onto#Machine(?m) ^ http://maccve/onto#Package(?p) ^ http://maccve/onto#CVE(?c) ^ http://maccve/onto#mcontains(?m, ?p) ^ http://maccve/onto#has_CVE(?p, ?c) -> http://maccve/onto#contains_CVE(?m, ?c) """

        rule = owl.Imp()
        rule.set_as_rule(swrl_rule)
        onto.save(file=output_file, format="rdfxml")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

So let's try with this ontology
@prefix : <http://maccve/onto#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .

:Machine a owl:Class .
:CVE a owl:Class .
:Package a owl:Class .

# Machine contains Package
:mcontains a owl:ObjectProperty ;
         rdfs:domain :Machine ;
         rdfs:range :Package .

# Package has_CVE CVE
:has_CVE a owl:ObjectProperty ;
         rdfs:domain :Package ;
         rdfs:range :CVE .

# Cette property est determinée par swrl
:contains_CVE a owl:ObjectProperty ;
         rdfs:domain :Machine ;
         rdfs:range :CVE .


:www1 a owl:NamedIndividual, :Machine .
:www2 a owl:NamedIndividual, :Machine .

:apache12 a owl:NamedIndividual, :Package .
:apache22 a owl:NamedIndividual, :Package .

:CVE1212 a owl:NamedIndividual, :CVE .

:www1 :mcontains :apache12 .
:www2 :mcontains :apache22 .
:apache22 :has_CVE :CVE1212 .

if the rule work it will infer that machine :www2 :mcontains a :CVE1212
The tool must take an xml in input, so before adding the rule you must convert it to xml
